# Get WPF single path data from . png file

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to convert png file(transparent icon) to  WPF "path data".
Any idea how to get single wpf path data from .png icon.?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do this in code, or that you want to do it using an application?

Comment: No, I don't want to do this by code, I just want to apply .png Image as wpf path. just like     <Path x:Name="Path" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  Data="F1 M 816.164, Z "/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it. A PNG file is a raster format (i.e. it stores the colour of each pixel in the image). WPF Path Data is a vector format (i.e. it stores the image as geometric drawing instructions). If you are unsure what this means, see [here](http://www.graphicdesignforum.com/forum/forum/graphic-design/resources/89-an-explanation-of-raster-vs-vector) for more info.

Vector can be converted to raster (at a set size), but raster cannot be obviously converted to vector (which is what you want).

The only way to try and convert raster to vector, with varying results, is to "trace" the raster image to guess what the equivalent geometric vector instructions might possibly be. The ability to trace a raster image accurately is directly proportional to its pixel dimensions and complexity of graphics. So tracing a [presumably] small icon might not be possible at all.

If I were faced with your problem, I would get as high a quality PNG image as possible, import it into Adobe Illustrator, use the Illustrator tracing tools to trace the image, and finally export the result of the trace to XAML (using something like http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/).

If you are looking for runtime tracing, this is something I have not come across. Given the massively varying tracing parameters which are required for different styles of raster images, I don't suppose it would even be realistically possible.

Good luck.